# Results of loop for XPath query run twice?

Tags: java, xml, loops, xpath, repeat

I want to print out the group results of an XPath expression that combines queries with the | operator. (It works, but there's a problem)

My XPath expression is:

```
//y-axis-title/text() | /bar-chart/bars/bar[@number='4']/value/text() |//bar[@number='5']/value/text()
```

My code:

```
public void loadData() {
            dl.loadDocuments("input\\bars.xml");
            try {
                XPath yAxisTitle = XPath.newInstance("//y-axis-title/text() | /bar-chart/bars/bar[@number='4']/value/text() | //bar[@number='5']/value/text()");
                List<Text> elements = (List<Text>)yAxisTitle.selectNodes(dl.getInputDocument());
                for(int i=0; i<elements.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println(elements.get(i).getText());
                }
            } catch (JDOMException jde){
                System.out.println("JDOMException at Exercise1.loadData(): "+ jde.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it prints out this:

```
Length
140
120
Length
140
120
```

while it's only supposed to print out this (my expected result):

```
Length
140
120
```

Somewhere something must be executing my loop twice. I don't know what it is. It doesn't make sense to me, because there are 3 resultsets within that grouped expression and therefor the counter is 3. I checked this while debugging. Where is this '2' (i.e. run it twice) coming from?

How do I fix this so I get my expected result?

Thanks.

Edit: A sample **bars.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<bar-chart> 
  <title>Bar Chart: Lengths</title> 
  <x-axis-title>Items</x-axis-title> 
  <y-axis-title>Length</y-axis-title> 
  <value>25</value> 
  <bars>
    <bar number="1">
      <value>90</value>
    </bar> 
  </bars> 
</bar-chart>
```

Comment: Could you please post an abbreviated sample of `bars.xml`?

Comment: `
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bar-chart>
 <title>Bar Chart: Lengths</title>
 <x-axis-title>Items</x-axis-title>
 <y-axis-title>Length</y-axis-title>
 <value>25</value>
 <bars> 
  <bar number="1"><value>90</value></bar>
 </bars>
</bar-chart>
`

Comment: Can you `System.out.println` something at the beginning and at the end of your method, please? This will tell you whether it's problem in the code you've shown to us, and related to XPath in any way, or whether your method is being called twice by some other code.

Comment: Can't repro: when the provided XPath expression is evaluated on the provided XML document, only a single text node ("Length") is selected. Please, edit the question and provide an XML document and XPath expression that don't contradict your reported results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks O. R. Mapper, that fixed my problem.

**Fix**:
Remove **loadData()** from the *constructor* of the Exercise1 class (the same class where the content of loadData() is, as shown in my question).

The problem was that loadData() was already being called somewhere else:
in the *constructor* of my **Controller** class:

```
public SimpleXPathController(ISimpleXPath doc){
    model = doc;
    model.loadData();
}
```

and in the *constructor* of the Exercise1 class as well:

```
public Exercise1(){
    dl = new DocumentLoader();
    loadData();
}
```

Finally, in my UI class I had this call:

```
SimpleXPathController simpleXPathController = new SimpleXPathController(new Exercise1());
```

resulting in:
1) The controller doing a call to *loadData()*
2) Exercise1 instance doing a call to *loadData()*

I troubleshot it by putting:

System.out.println("testing1"); at the beginning of the try{} block 
and
System.out.println("testing2") at the end of the try{} block.

Problem solved.